# java.io.NotSerializableException error

Tags: java, jdbc

I ran into a not serializable exception error after running my application.

The error stack shows the following:

```
 SEVERE: IOException while loading persisted sessions: java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: br.dao.DriverManagerDAOFactory
java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: br.dao.DriverManagerDAOFactory
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1963)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1887)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1770)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1346)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:368)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.readObject(StandardSession.java:1496)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.readObjectData(StandardSession.java:998)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.doLoad(StandardManager.java:394)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.load(StandardManager.java:321)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.start(StandardManager.java:648)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.setManager(ContainerBase.java:446)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4631)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:675)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1317)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1065)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: br.dao.DriverManagerDAOFactory
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1180)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1528)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1493)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.writeObject(StandardSession.java:1572)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.writeObjectData(StandardSession.java:1015)
```

So I did the following hoping to rectify the problem :

```
class DriverManagerDAOFactory extends DAOFactory implements Serializable{
    private String url;
    private String username;
    private String password;

    DriverManagerDAOFactory(String url, String username, String password) {
        this.url = url;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        return DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
    }
}
```

Even though, after I implemented Serializable, the error still shows up...any clue about this?? : /

Comment: Is there a reason you don't have a `serialVersionUID`? Your compiler should warn you about that.

Answer (score 4):

Is your super-class `DAOFactory` serializable? Also did your change get picked up in class path correctly? It may be possible that software is running with earlier jar/classes.

Comment: oh wow, thanks...my daofactory wasn't serializable..doh..thanks!! it's fine now!

Answer (score 1):

Connections should not and cannot be serialised. Your DAOFactory is not serialisable for a similar reason. The problem I suppose is because your factory object is referenced/stored in your session and hence when your session is serialised, your DAOFactory is also getting serialised, resulting in the Exception. You should take a closer look as to why your session should contain your factory object.

Comment: Humm okay wow, I took out serializable for my daofactory and DriverManagerDAOFactory , and I ran my application again, there was no error...this is so weird..